# Native c++ dll running slower when called from VB.net vs. running called from native .exe

Tags: .net, c++, vb.net, dll, c++-cli

I have some code in native C++ (Visual C++ 2010) to process a file of some GB. I compiled it to an .exe and it takes about 8 minutes. But I need to call it from a Visual Basic .net interface, so I put it in a .dll and created a c++/cli wrapper class to call my code in a native dll. The only interaction between the managed code and native dll is to call the function that initiates the processing. To my surprise the processing takes almost double the the time that takes the .exe way. I´m not really an expert in VB.net so maybe there are some settings or something to look at I don´t know. Any idea welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of processsing is happening inside your code? Does your exe file need 100% processor time, or do you make a lot of file I/O?

Comment: Did you put your native C++ code into a lib or DLL and made sure it is exactly the same lib used either in your native exe / in your .NET wrapper? This is something you should try first.

Comment: Code that processes large files is almost always throttled by the file system.  Reading a multi-gigabyte file takes a while, hard disks are quite slow.  What matters a great deal is whether or not the file was read before and thus cached in the file system cache, whether there's enough free RAM to allow the file to fit in the cache and how badly the file is fragmented.  The only safe way to compare is to use the *same* file and run the timing test from a cold boot.

Comment: The code reads a file, process the information, creates several temporary files, creates some images, and finishes. The processor is running at 50% against less than 30% in .exe mode.

Comment: @Daniel: are you absolutely sure you did not eventually compile your C++ code to managed code when creating the .NET wrapper? Or that you did not use an unoptimized debug version for the .NET version?

Comment: -are you absolutely sure you did not eventually compile your C++ code to managed code: I created a separated dll from the managed dll and the common language runtime support is disabled. About unoptimized version, I don´t know, I´m using vb.net express version.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas:

- Maybe you built the .exe using the Release configuration, but the .dll was set to Debug. You sometimes see a big difference between release and debug builds, optimized code makes a huge difference.
- If your VB.net does anything besides calling the C++ code then it could be adding CPU load on top of what your .dll consumes. Any kind of background processing done on the VB.net side could account for the difference. To compare apples to apples you should have a command line VB.net app w/o GUI and with a single line that calls the dll function.
- If the above doesn't help I recommend that you create a native C++ app that links against this same DLL and compare this against the native exe version. If the C++ and DLL version performs the same as the C++ standalone exe then there's got to be something on the VB.net side that is consuming additional CPU. If, on the other side, the DLL is also slow when called from native C++ then you should look for differences in your build process for exe vs. dll, or for differences in macros/conditional compilations for exe vs. dll mode.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does the C++/CLI wrapper really just call the DLL function, or does it load the DLL itself, then stick around and get managed by .NET?  Is the native procedure getting its own thread, or a thread created in .NET's context?  My gut is that .NET is doing something unnecessary to manage the lifetime of the object, the DLL, or the thread.

My suggestion is therefore to add an Event to indicate the DLL being finished with whatever it's doing, start a new thread from the native DLL to run the procedure, and return the event handle immediately.  Have your .NET wait on that handle wherever it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not really understand why the native dll called from DotNet side can double the processing time unless you can give more details.

However, if the native exe version works as expected, you can run the native exe as background process from the DotNet, passing api parameters via command line. You can even redirect the exe's console output to DotNet based GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. I'ld look at all columns present in task manager and compare the both processes (working set size, page faults, ...). Then I'ld look at performance monitor and look into the cache manager values. Last but not least you could try only reading from files and not writing to see where the time is spent.

Answer (score -1):

The .NET framework imposes some overhead in communicating from its "managed" code to native or "unmanaged" code.  [See here for some background.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

So what you are seeing in performance terms is what I'd expect in general terms.  If the native DLL were doing more work, I'd expect the communication overhead (efficiency penalty) to be a lower percentage.

Comment: The way I understand the question, there's just a single call from managed to native code. So the communication overhead can hardly explain the increase from 8 minute to almost double the time.

Comment: That´s right, the managed class calls only once the native code to start the processing.

Comment: -1, you did not read the problem description thourougly. It says clearly "one call for initiating the processsing".

Comment: I stand by my answer.  The user process does not run uninterruptedly under Windows, and every time the process is interrupted and reinstated, the thread's stack has to be saved and restored.  When you have the native DLL code running underneath the calling code from .NET + marshalling, there's more to save and restore.  Here's an experiment to test the idea:  try increasing the priority at which the user process runs.  Fewer interruptions should mean less overhead.

Comment: @hardmath: TThe stack is just pages of (virtual) memory. Windows does _not_ swap out memory if there's sufficient memory. Even if it does, it swaps out the Least Recently Used pages, and that's never the top of stack. Furthermore, given that the processor runs at 50%, changing CPU priority won't matter at all.

Comment: @MSalters:  It might not make much difference, but it's a really cheap experiment for the OP to do.  I will provide additional links on the overhead of file IO in unmanaged code being resolved through .NET "security" mechanisms and propose a more elaborate experiment to test that effect.

Comment: Save yourself the scare quotes; that's equally untrue. There's no security imposed by .Net on unmanaged code. That's still calling KERNEL32.DLL

Comment: @hardmath: if you can prove your theory that just calling unmanaged code from managed by a single starting call can double the runtime for a scenario like the OP described, just because of more "stack save/restore overhead", I will turn my downvote into an upvote. But so far I find your explanation not reasonable.